# Honda Clarity 2018 HMU Replacement

Tags: honda, head-unit, infotainment, parts-replacement

I am looking to replace the HMU assembly in my Clarity 2018 PHEV (non-touring).  As far as I can surmise, the steps would consist of: removing the trim cover, removing both screws, unplugging the 6-pin connector, and swapping that entire unit out for another.  Will this work upon installation, or will I need to perform other steps, e.g., re-flashing the unit, restoring/overwriting the data, recovery, etc?

In regards to the HMU data, I have root access to the original unit and I've already taken both a backup through the diagnostics menu (as in the one you invoke via  holding Power + Menu + Brightness, then holding Menu again), as well as an ADB backup on the Android side through DevOps > USB Debugging (Enabled) > Wifi Debugging (Enabled).  I also have a copy of recovery.sh so I can boot the new unit into recovery and flash it with the data from my unit.  Barring these steps, I'm aware that the VIN can still be manually set from the diagnostics menu, but I don't believe this impairs the unit's function because mine had come with an incorrect VIN entry from the factory (missing one digit).

In either case, I'm not aware of any other security mechanisms that I would need to contend with in order to install the new unit, but is there something that I'm simply not aware of?